# How to install Python 3.6+ version in Kali Linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I need help. I newone in Linux OS and in Python at all.

I need to install python interpreter v. 3.6 for my current project. The reason is - lib, that i would like to use doesn't work on 3.7+
I use Pycharm and want to set new environment with interpreter 3.6. I know that i can set it in settings/project/python interpreter. But i can see only python v2,v2.7,v3,v3.9.
How can i add 3.6 version? Please, help)

command **apt install python3.6**  doen't help me.

```
└─# apt install python3.6                                                                2 ⨯
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.6'
```

About OS:

```
└─# cat /etc/os-release                                                                127 ⨯
PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali
VERSION="2021.1"
VERSION_ID="2021.1"
VERSION_CODENAME="kali-rolling"
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="https://www.kali.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.kali.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.kali.org/"
```

**Serge Ballesta** helped me. Thanks a lot!
Just for silly ubuntu users like me - "how to install some source distribution"

Extract the .tar.gz or (.tar.bz2) file with the following commands

```
tar xvzf PACKAGENAME.tar.gz
```

Navigate to the extracted folder using cd command

```
cd PACKAGENAME
```

Now run the following command to install the tarball

```
./configure

sudo make install
```

Comment: Which distribution?

Comment: …and which version?

Comment: `add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && apt-get update`, then try `apt install python3.6`.

Comment: Regardless of distribution, you could consider [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

Comment: Use virtual env

Comment: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/ let you manage virtual environments on you machine, if you do not need pythn3.6 to be at system level, of course

Comment: Capie MarcoP Since when does virtualenv manage Python versions as well as package versions? Did I miss something?

Comment: @Thomas you can for example use `pyenv` together with `poetry` to have power over all versions

Comment: @user8408080 I'm currently a fan of that combination of tools myself... but it's pyenv that installs/manages Python versions, not virtualenv.

Comment: @Thomas ah okay, sorry I misunderstood you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all Unix distributions offer all Python versions. It is common to only have one Python 2.7.x version and one or two Python 3.y .

Normally Python 3 has a good ascending compatibility, so a Python 3.9 should run a Python 3.6 without any problem. If you really need a specific version, the *desperate* way is to get a source distribution from python.org and build it locally. The downside is that this one will not participate in `apt` version control, so it will not be detected by third party application. But it is the only way I know to have a no longer distribution maintained version.

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't know how to install it, but google helped me)

Comment: Using virtual environments might be more useful

Comment: In my experience, there are lots of packages that don't work on 3.9 yet (or at least didn't when I tried a few months ago), mostly those that rely on bytecode/JIT/runtime internals, which changed between 3.8 and 3.9. Librosa is one example; gdal is another.

Answer (score 1):

First remove older version

```
sudo apt purge -y python2-minimal
```

Remove unwanted libraries of old version

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

install new version

```
sudo apt install -y python3-pip
```

latest version of python is successfully installed!

check version

```
python --version
```

Comment: Please do spend a minute to see how to properly format your code snippets (done it for you, this time).

Answer (score 1):

see details: https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/python3.6

> [2019-02-05] python3.6 3.6.8-1 removed from kali-rolling (KaliRepository
>
> > [2019-01-28] python3.6 3.6.8-1 removed from kali-dev (Kali Repository)

as seen, python3.6 removed than the Kali repository.

please, download the python3.6 using following url

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/

Comment: Please do not write in all-bold (edited).

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
$sudo apt-get update
```

and then run

```
$sudo apt-get python3.6
```